# SPCascadeDropdowns - Works for all items, except one - has got me puzzled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, spservices, cascading

I've been using SPCascadeDropdowns for several years and have not had any issues...until now and it has got me puzzled.

Here's the setup:
  SP 2010 Enterprise
  jquery-1.8.3
  SPServices-0.7.2
  Parent List: Requests
  Child List: Request Note
  Child List: Request Task
  Child List: Request Task Activity
  Child List: Request Issue

As expected, changing the parent dropdown triggers the cascading changes to the child dropdowns. With the exception of one parent list item (1 of 75).  Even though that parent list item has verified children in two of the child lists (as seen is the last screenshot below), the child dropdowns do not filter for this one item.

I am at a loss trying to figure this problem out and any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Here are a couple of screenshots of the SPCascadeDropdowns working and not working:
*SPCascadeDropdowns Working*
[image: SPCascadeDropdowns working]

*SPCascadeDropdowns Not Working*
[image: SPCascadeDropdowns not working]

Here is a screenshot of the parent and child list items, for the one that is not working.  To show the relationship the related ID is circled.
[image: SPCascadeDropdowns Parent-Child Lists]

Answer (score 0):

For the ones not working, do you have duplicates for those values in the relationship list?

Try adding the option "matchOnId: true" to your call.